# dynamically Updating the table through python

Tags: python, sql, cx-oracle

I want to update a table(TEMP):

```
value = 100 * 0.9
statement = 'update temp set tax = :1 where name = :2'
cur.execute(statement, ('value', 'emp1'))
con.commit()
```

Is there any other way to update the table dynamically?

Comment: There are (infinitely?) many ways to do anything. What are you actually asking?

Comment: Table is not getting updated in this way!

I am trying to update

Comment: Is it updated if you write `update temp set tax = 'value' where name = 'emp1'; commit;` directly into the database, without python? If it is not, your problem is not in python.

Answer (score 1):

Take the quotes off of value.

```
value = 100 * 0.9
statement = 'update temp set tax = :1 where name = :2'
cur.execute(statement, (value, 'emp1'))
con.commit()
```

You were passing in the string 'value' not your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code since I don't know you're specific database information. Code similar to this should work:

```
import pymysql

con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='random',
                  passwd='pass', db='sample')

cur = con.cursor()

value = 100 * 0.9
name = 'emp1'
cur.execute('''UPDATE temp SET tax = %d where name = %s'''
          %(value, name))
con.commit()
```

Comment: I  have tried to put this way as well but no luck!
I am using a Oracle 11g

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
table, tax, name = 'temp', 100 * 0.9, 'emp1'
statement = f'update {table} set tax = :1 where name = :2'
cur.execute(statement, (tax, name))
con.commit()
```

Comment: Below is the error I'm getting

**cur.execute(statement)

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended**

Comment: May you are missing ';' or some symbol somewhere in your sql statement

Comment: used same as the above! 
also tried this way
cur.execute(f'update temp set tax = {tax} where name = {name}')

Comment: @SKB I edited the answer. Maybe you can print the statement and try it at database.

Comment: This does not use bind variables and is prone to SQL injection attacks, not to mention performance concerns!